# Appstore API Invalid Vendor number

Tags: python, api, app-store

I am trying to use the API on Appstore. I am using python to connnect and I get the  Invalid Vendor number error.

```
payload = {'filter[frequency]':'DAILY', 'filter[reportSubType]': 'SUMMARY', 'filter[reportDate]':'2019-03-01', 'filter[vendorNumber]': '12345678', 'filter[reportType]': 'SALES' }
```

Here is the request call:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports', headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)}, params=payload)
```

Here is the error that platform returns:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "id" : "285874b4-16fb-4109-b810-ffa2973be714",
    "status" : "400",
    "code" : "PARAMETER_ERROR.INVALID",
    "title" : "A parameter has an invalid value",
    "detail" : "Invalid vendor number specified. Try again.",
    "source" : {
      "parameter" : "filter[vendorNumber]"
    }
  } ]
}
```

The platform does not like the Vendor number. Any one else raninto this issue and were able to figure out a solution to this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is `12345678` really your vendor number? It looks suspect. You can find your vendor number at the top of the page in [Payments and Financial Reports](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/itc/payments_and_financial_reports#/).